# Using stacks to check balance of HTML tags in c

Tags: html, c, stack

I am trying to check the HTML tags balance using a stack in c. Here's what my code looks like:

```
void tagcheck()
    {
        FILE *fp;
        fp=fopen("html.txt","r");
        char ch;
        while(ch=getc(fp)!=EOF)
        {
            if(ch =='<')
            {   
                push(ch);

                while(ch=getc(fp)!='>')
                {
                     if(ch=='/')
                     {
                        pop();
                        while(ch!='<')
                        {
                           ch=getc(fp);
                           pop();
                        }
                           pop();
                           continue;
                    }
                    else if(ch=='!')
                    {
                     pop();
                     continue;
                    }
                    push(ch);
               }
          }
      }
if(s->top=-1)
{
    printf("No Tag Error\n");       
}
else
    printf("Tag error\n");
    fclose(fp);
}
```

When I try to run it, for some reason the `ch=='<'` condition is false and the loop is kind of wasted. What's the problem with it?

I have checked the file name and path which has no issues.

Comment: Have you tried to step through that code with a debugger?

Comment: 1) `while(ch=getc(fp)!=EOF)` is the same as `while(ch= (getc(fp)!=EOF))`.  So `ch` will have the value of 0 or 1. 2) Use `int ch`

Comment: `while(ch=getc(fp)!=EOF)` should have generated a warning.  Save time, enable all warnings.